# SWRevealController in Swift Crashing with Optional,

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am Using SWRevealViewController in my swift project. Its crashing because of Optional value. I am Unable to solve this Issue. Can anybody help me.
Thank you. I am adding my source code with FB file from my group. Please Check this.

[Project Here Click to download](https://www.facebook.com/download/1455127764809499/RewealController.zip)

Comment: If anybody know the answer help me

Answer (score 0):

I downlaod you project , you make mistake with Slide front(this menu items) 
remove

```
 @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()!
menuButton.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

slide menu shouldnt has bar item